# Making ListView in a WinForm Sortable?

Tags: c#, winforms, sorting

In Windows' file explorer, you can sort ListViews by clicking on the column header to sort by.  Is it possible to add this type of functionality to a ListView in a WinForm?  If so, how can this be done?

Thanks! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is.  Have a look at this article:

[Sorting ListView Items by Column Using Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996467.aspx)

Comment: I see, so it's not just a quick fix.  I will see if I have time to implement this into my program (hopefully I will).

Comment: [ObjectListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net) would be a quick fix. It's a drop-in replacement for ListView that supports sorting (and many more features).

Comment: @RichardDingwall Just tried it. It's not a drop in replacement.